# Dialog box with EditText and Spinner

Tags: android, dialog

I have a button that pops up with a dialog box on click.

I want the dialog box to have an `EditText` and a `Spinner` inside the dialog box.

I don't know how I'd set the view for it, I have the code for an `AlertDialog` and it works, it's just the `EditText` and `Spinner` that I need to place inside it then I can get on with the rest of the app's code.

Please can someone show me how I'd add an `EditText` and `Spinner` please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1) Use `AlertDialog`'s [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View)) method.

2) Create an `Activity` with

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in your `AndroidManifest`.

Number one should be easier to do while number two will give you more flexibility.

Comment: What would I put inside the setView?
I've tried "R.layout.newfiledialog" but that doesn't work :(
I'm only a beginner!

Comment: `R.layout.newfiledialog` is just an int. you should inflate that view with an inflator.

Comment: Thank you SO much. I've been scratching my head at this for ages! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own customdialog. Declare your views in a layout and load it with the help of `AlertDialog` like the one mentioned in the sample:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog